# Gift Aid Declarations with overlapping dates

Tags: civicontribute, dates, gift-aid-extension

I work in the IT department, CiviCrm isn't my forté. I have been tasked with helping the marketing department with a few issues with Civi.

One issue that I keep scratching my head about is Gift Aid Declaration. When I try to edit a declaration / add a new one, it won't allow me to submit the form as dates overlap.

> x Start Date This declaration overlaps with the one from 11/05/2013
> to 07/22/2014
>
> x Start Date This declaration overlaps with the one from
> 12/31/1999 to 07/23/2014

Is there a setting I can change via Custom fields to allow dates to overlap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is 'No' there aren't any settings to allow this. Gift Aid declarations don't have to have an end date, when you sign up to Gift Aid to an organisation you can effectively sign up for ever (unless you specify an end date). Bearing this mind, I suggest that you change the end date of the previous declaration to avoid the overlap.